# How to crop stl file using python

Tags: python-2.7, stl, crop, vtk

I need to crop a `STL(Steriolithographic)` file using `python programming` using `co-ordinates` or `image dimensions` is there any way that any one can suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `vtk` does offer solutions for cutting `stl` objects.

Have a look at the class references for [vtkCutter](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCutter.html#details) and [vtkClipClosedSurface](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkClipClosedSurface.html). Here is a Python example for [cutting something with vtkCutter](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/FilledPolygon).

Without any code or specifics from your side, this is as much help as you can get.